# I am getting a Not Found Error When I refresh one of my url links

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, mern

I have a MERN project that I am hosting on an Amazon EC2. When I click on the public url of the EC2 instance ,It takes me to the home page (**<My_public_EC2_url>/**) which has a link to my blogs page (**<My_public_EC2_url>/blogs**). It seems to display the web page when I click on the link ,however, when I refresh the web page,I get a 404 not found error.

I am using nginx as web server. I suspect its something to do with that. Below is the **nginx.conf file**

```
upstream nodeapp{
     server node_app:3001;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html;
  
  location / {

   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

location /footer {
 proxy_pass http://nodeapp/footer;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }


  location /blog {
 proxy_pass http://nodeapp/blog;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /Comments/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/comments/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /Login/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/login/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /Logout/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/logout/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    location /Register/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/register/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    location /Users/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/users/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/css {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/css;
    }
    
    location /static/js {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/js;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico;
    }
    
}
```

Below are the front end routes

```
<AuthProvider>
       <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/blogs" element={<Blog/>}/>
         <Route path="/blogs/:id" element={<Single_blog />} />
         <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
         <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
         <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      
       </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>
     </AuthProvider>
```

Also, I am able to access my backend routes . Is there a way to block that?